# rails, make render add a HTML comment of the filename being rendered for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with an application whose is a bit complicated and was not designed by me. As it uses A LOT of partials, It would be really helpful if I could automatically add an html template each time a new erb/rhtml file is rendered.

So for exmaple if code have this:

```
<%= render(:partial => 'personal_details', :object => @auser) %>
```

the ouput html add something like:

```
<!-- Rendering: views/users/_personal_details.rhtml called from other_file.rhtml -->
```

How to acoomplish that?

Comment: You may need to patch how the `render` function works, so this might not be easy. Remember that `log/development.log` does usually provide a lot of detail as to what was rendered.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you already using [xray-rails](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails) to visualize your partials? It is an incredibly useful tool.

If you need something more than that, take a look at the xray-rails source code for some pointers. Essentially what you'll need to do is monkey-patch `ActionView::Template#render` as [shown here](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails/blob/v0.1.15/lib/xray/engine.rb#L30).

To summarize:

```
ActionView::Template.class_eval do
  def render_with_prepend_comment(*args, &block)
    # Defer to original implementation to do the actual render
    source = render_without_prepend_comment(*args, &block)

    # Then augment it as desired
    "<!-- prepended comment -->\n" + source 
  end
  alias_method_chain :render, :prepend_comment
end
```

There's a little more to it; see how xray-rails does [its augmentation](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails/blob/v0.1.15/lib/xray-rails.rb#L82).

Answer (score 1):

Rails >= 6.1 includes an option for ActionView called `annotate_rendered_view_with_filenames` which determines whether to annotate rendered view with template file names. This defaults to `false`.

In your case, you probably want to add the following to your `development.rb` configuration file:

```rb
  # Annotate rendered view with file names.
  config.action_view.annotate_rendered_view_with_filenames = true
```

This results in commented annotations similar to these in your rendered HTML:

```html
<!-- BEGIN app/views/layouts/partials/_header.html.erb -->
  <header></header>
<!-- END app/views/layouts/partials/_header.html.erb -->
```

Here is the description from the [guides](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cb5765a12751ca03866a89cf19fefcbc2d93a8ea/guides/source/configuring.md#configaction_viewannotate_rendered_view_with_filenames) and here is the [implemenation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/668d866b4bf117012b6f7e400770c0a4c62fb560/actionview/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb#L59) in Rails itself.

Answer (score 0):

[This gem](https://github.com/duncanbeevers/rails_view_annotator) claims to support the functionality you desire.